# ListView Item binding does not work

Tags: asp.net, listview, binding, webforms

I'm new to asp.net(webforms). I follow this tutorial --> http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/ui_and_navigation

in the Site.Master I've added the following code as described in the tutorial:

```
    <section style="text-align: center; background-color: #fff">
        <asp:ListView ID="categoryList"
            ItemType="VanchoWorks.Models.Category"
            runat="server"
            SelectionMethod="GetCategories" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <b style="font-size: large; font-style: normal">
                    <a href="/ProductList.aspx?id=<%#: Item.CategoryID %>">
                        <%#: Item.CategoryName %>
                    </a>
                </b>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemSeparatorTemplate> - </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </section>
```

in the code-behind(Site.Master.cs)

```
    public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        var db = new ProductContext();
        IQueryable<Category> query = db.Categories;
        return query;
    }
```

But no sign of ListView is shown when I run the application. I added breakpoint in GetCategories() line 1, but it does not stop there, which makes me think I've not setup the SelectionMethod very well. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change SelectionMethod="GetCategories" to SelectMethod="GetCategories"

Answer (score 0):

Bind the listview Like this

```
public  GetCategories()
    {
        var db = new ProductContext();
        IQueryable<Category> query = db.Categories;

        ListView1.DataSource=query;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
```

call this method in page load **Remove  SelectionMethod="GetCategories"**  from html other vise it will show errors.

Hope it will help you